# Newton's second law of motion with variable mass - equation check

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

I am going through a text book and its rather confusing:

So the topic is newton's second law and how it relates to the change of momentum. Everything is quite basic and clear but then it showed an example :

Suppose a train is going at a speed of $v_x$ in the horizontal direction. The train will however be loaded with sand at a constant speed, i.e. $\frac{dm}{dt}=A$ and there is no force acting on the train., i.e. $0=m\frac{dv}{dt}+Av$

Then the book goes on to conclude"... with $m=m_0+At$ we have $$ln\frac{v}{v_0}=ln\frac{m_0}{m_0+At}$$

I have absolutely no idea how it came to this. Can someone help?

Comment: Is it $A*t$ or $A*v$? $m = m_0 + A*v$ is not dimensionally consistent. Also, this is a basic first order differential equation that can be solved by separating $dv$ and $v$ terms to one side and integrating the expression from limits $v_0$ to $v_f$

Comment: @Cross oh yeah sorry made a mistake...

Comment: [Transfer of Material Systems](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_chapter12.1_12.3.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple differential equation. Say, $m(t) = m_0 + At$

$$
0 = m(t) \frac{dv}{dt} + A v 
\\
\frac{dv}{v} = - \frac{A}{m(t)}dt = - \frac{A}{m_0 + At}dt
$$

Since $\frac{dv}{v} = d(\ln{v})$ and $\frac{A}{m_0 + At}dt = \frac{dAt}{m_0 + At} = d(\ln{(m_0 + At)})$, we can write

$$
d(\ln{v}) = - d(\ln{(m_0 + At)}),
\\
\ln{\frac{v_{final}}{v_{initial}}} = - \ln{\frac{m_{0}+At_{final}}{m_0}} = \ln{\frac{m_0}{m_{0}+At_{final}}}
$$

That's it.

Comment: Maybe also mention that the first differential equation comes from Newtons second law, which, in its general form, is $F =\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{dm}{dt}v + m\frac{dv}{dt}$. For a constant mass, this reduces to the better known $F = ma$.

Comment: Newton's second law does not work with a variable mass

Comment: @wolphram-jonny On the other hand, momentum conservation law works. Initial momentum plus gained momentum from external net force equals to the final momentum: $(m+dm)v + Fdt = m(v+dv) + dm(v+u) $, where u is the relative force. $m dv + u dm = F dt$ and, finally, $F = m \dot{v} + \dot{m} u$.

Comment: So technically Newton's second law works for the variable mass but it must be applied to both remaining mass and the mass that leaves the body of consideration.